# matlab equivalent of python sklearn train_test_split function?

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, cross-validation

How can I get in matlab the equivalent of the python code

`x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = sk.cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y)`

The train and test dataset should be randomly sampled because I will repeat this procedure more times to perform bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have 150 samples that you want to split into 100 samples for training and 50 samples for testing. You could just do:

Python:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.random.permutation(range(len(y)))
X_train, y_train = X[idx[:100]], y[idx[:100]]
X_test, y_test = X[idx[100:]], y[idx[100:]]
```

MATLAB/Octave:

```
idx = randperm(length(y))
X_train, y_train = X(idx(1:100)), y(idx(1:100))
X_test, y_test = X(idx(100:150)), y(idx(100:150))
```